# Problems with special chars when extracting Mail

Tags: applescript, mail.app

I am using this script for saving a mail out from the Apple Mail app:

```
tell application "Mail"
    
    # take the selected Mail
    set selectedMessages to selected messages of message viewer 0
    set mailToSave to first item of selectedMessages
    
    set resultFile to (choose file name with prompt "Speichere E-Mail unter ..." default name "Mail.eml") as rich text
    if resultFile does not end with ".eml" then set resultFile to resultFile & ".eml"
    
    my writeTextToFile(source of mailToSave, resultFile, true)
    
end tell

on writeTextToFile(theText, theFile, overwriteExistingContent)
    try
        
        -- Convert the file to a string
        set theFile to theFile as string
        
        -- Open the file for writing
        set theOpenedFile to open for access file theFile with write permission
        
        -- Clear the file if content should be overwritten
        if overwriteExistingContent is true then set eof of theOpenedFile to 0
        
        -- Write the new content to the file
        write theText to theOpenedFile starting at eof
        
        -- Close the file
        close access theOpenedFile
        
        -- Return a boolean indicating that writing was successful
        return true
        
        -- Handle a write error
    on error
        
        -- Close the file
        try
            close access file theFile
        on error errMsg
            log errMsg
        end try
        
        -- Return a boolean indicating that writing failed
        return false
    end try
end writeTextToFile
```

In most of the cases it's working perfectly, but it some cases the special chars are broken in the exported file. For example:

One mail is displayed correctly in Mail. If I open the source of this mail I'll get this:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
X-Mailer: .......

...

fÃ¼r Sie ...
```

In Mail the text is correctly shown as a `für Sie ...`.

The exported file contains:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
X-Mailer: ...

...

fÌ1Ú4r Sie ...
```

If I drag and drop this mail out of Apple Mail, it's getting saved correctly. Any way how I can achieve this with AppleScript?

Comment: How are you seeing the source - what tool to see the characters

Comment: In Apple Mail: View > Message > Raw Source. The .eml-file I open with VS Code.

Comment: OK its UTF which I don't understand but neither look correct. I think you need to see what the class of the text https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-BBCIAHJF is you need (Sorry I can't help as seems to be unlike other languages here)

Comment: I added `set mailSource to source of mailToSave` and `log class of mailSource`. The result is `(*rich text*)`

Comment: The problem is: Apple Mail seems to convert the source. A `ü` is saved as `C3BC`. `source of ...` converts it to `Ã¼`, what is `C383C2BC`.

Comment: Well the C3BC looks correct to me . Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218631/applescript-reading-a-text-file-with-utf8-class-triggers-error

Comment: I tried that... but still the problem is, that `source of ...` delivers `Ã¼` instead of `ü`. Maybe it's a bug in Apple Mail?!

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a pattern as to which emails are so affected? For example, they're sent from a single company or with a specific email client?

Comment: Yes, they are coming always from the same sender (not only one, several ones). I will study your answer now, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I figured out an own way as I am now using JavaScript:

```
var source = mailToSave.source();
var newSource = decodeURIComponent(escape(source));
```

To get the final result, I need to save it as an UTF-8-String, what is only working with `NSString`:

```
writeTextToFile(newFilePath.toString(), newSource);

function writeTextToFile(pathString, textToWrite) { 
    // convert to NSString
    var nsString = $.NSString.alloc.initWithUTF8String(textToWrite)
  
    // convert to NSPath
    var nsPath = $(pathString).stringByStandardizingPath
  
    // write File
    var success = nsString.writeToFileAtomicallyEncodingError(nsPath, false, $.NSUTF8StringEncoding, null)
  
    if (!success) {
        throw new Error("Write failed. ERROR: Writing to file failed.\nPath: " + pathString)
    }
  
    return success
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would speculate that the original email was converted (or orginates as such) to a windows encoding (e.g. something-1252) which Mail then converted to utf-8.

You can't see —to my knowledge— what's happening in script editor but you could if you use [Satimage's Smile](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/downloads/index.html) which has two [internal commands](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/smile/text/unicode_and_applescript.html#number): `unicode number` and `unicode character`. Alas that they don't seem portable.

```
unicode number "für"
--> {102, 252, 114}

unicode number "für" encoding «class utf8»
--> {102, 195, 188, 114}

unicode character {195, 188}
--> "Ã¼"
```

With the [satimage osax](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/downloads/downloads_companion_osaxen.html) installed, you can use the `readtext` and `writetext` [commands](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/dictionaries/dict_satimage.html#SatimageTextAdditions) to save to a file in a different encoding and then get its contents.

```
use scripting additions -- specifically Satimage.osax must be installed
set sText to "fÃ¼r Sie"
set pd to ((path to desktop) as text)
writetext sText to file (pd & "brk2.txt")

set au1 to readtext file (pd & "brk2.txt") encoding "UTF-8"
--> "fÃ¼r Sie"
writetext au1 to file (pd & "fixed.txt") encoding "windows-1252"
readtext file (pd & "fixed.txt")
--> "für Sie"
```

In case you would rather work with the text inline, then other tools are required. If we take it outside of applescript and examine it in the shell using `iconv`, we can see some of the sordid details. NB Obviously I don't know which text encoding is actually responsible but I'll guess that its 'WINDOWS-1252' and as 'cp1252' is synonymous and shorter, I'll use that.

This takes the expected character and converts it from CP-1252 to UTF-8.

```
% echo 'ü' | iconv -f cp1252 -t utf-8
--> Ã¼
```

My guess is that some piece of infrastructure along the way (e.g. sending mail client, mail server, intervening gateway) is treating the text as being windows encoded. Then another piece (e.g. your mail server or client) is treating it as utf-8, and the result is a mess.

This probably won't work in all scenarios (because more than one conversion could occur en route) but in this case, a single transform suffices.

Update: Since you're writing to a file, it's probably easiest to just have iconv read the file directly.

```
set pdk to ((path to desktop) as text) & "deskfil.txt"
set pf to POSIX path of pdk
do shell script "iconv -t cp1252 -f utf-8 " & pf
```

So if you can put the corrupted text into a variable, it's straightforward to get the shell to process it.

I found inspiration from this helpful answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14985394/7410243. Hopefully, my use of terminology here is reasonably correct.

Comment: thank you very much. It tried it in the shell and it's working. But how can I apply it on a multiple-line string? `set mailSource to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of mailSource & " | iconv -t cp1252 -f utf-8"` is bringing me an error `cannot convert`

Comment: What specifically cannot be converted? I can't see your string. The -c option for iconv will skip unruly characters. I don't think that error has anything to do with multi-line input, but I'll expand the answer to try and deal with multi-line.

Comment: While not mentioned at its site, nonetheless, it's my understanding that satimage osax does not work with **macOS Big Sur** and later, although I've not tested it.